# what is session sharing and how to do session sharing between IIS servers

Tags: 2013, asp.net, iis

we published an internet web application and many users access it daily,

we have load balanced in our environment and 4 web front end servers  here by default IIS 8.5 will share sessions or we need to configure any settings in IIS

in these servers IIS web application deployed on port 443